# Export Oracle database column headers with column names into csv

Tags: python, oracle, csv, export

I am making a program that fetches column names and dumps the data into csv format.
Now everything is working just fine and data is being dumped into csv, the problem is,
I am not able to fetch headers into csv. If I open the exported csv file into excel, only data shows up not the column headers. How do I do that?

Here's my code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(--Details--)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(--Details--)

d = conn.cursor()

csv_file = open("profile.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
d.execute("""
select * from all_tab_columns where OWNER = 'ABBAS'
""")
tables_tu = d.fetchall()
for row in tables_tu:
    writer.writerow(row)

conn.close()
csv_file.close()
```

What code do I use to export headers too in csv?

Comment: Try out `writer.writerow(i[0] for i in d.description)` just before your `for` loop.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988159/better-ways-to-print-out-column-names-when-using-cx-oracle

Comment: Thanks A lot man! it worked :)

Comment: @MuhammadAbbas: you're welcome. I also posted an answer with that information.

Comment: For a large number of rows, you should tune [`cursor.arraysize`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#tuning-fetch-performance) for best performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this just above your `for` loop:

```
writer.writerow(i[0] for i in d.description)
```

Because `d.description` is a read-only attribute containing 7-tuples that look like:

```
(name, 
type_code, 
display_size,
internal_size, 
precision, 
scale, 
null_ok)
```